# How to upgrade iPhone iOS version 4.3.5 to 5.0.1?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I am using iOS version 4.3.5 in my iPhone,

I want to upgrade it to version 5.0.1,

Currently if i will connect with iTunes it's give me update to version 5.1.1,

But i needed a version 5.0.1,

Please any one tell me how can i download iOS 5.0.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can only update to the latest version of iOS via iTunes, you might be able to update to 5.0.1 if you manage to find the correct `ipsw` for your iPhone.

You can select the ipsw to update you phone with.

Comment: Thanks for answer, can you please tell me abt ipsw file, that is may be type of jailbrake or what. It may be affecting for my iPhone os?

Comment: No the [`IPSW`](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=IPSW_File_Format) file format is the way Apple distributes there iOS software.

Answer (score 1):

I think stackoferflow isn't the place to ask this kind of questions, but if you google ios 5.0.1 download I'm sure you will find the donwload

Then, you can install it with itunes, but you have to hold alt key while you click update, then you can choose the firmware on your hard drive